# Maximum Likelihood Estimation - Choosing between nlm and nloptr

Tags: r

I am attempting to find three parameters by minimizing a negative log-likelihood function in R. I have attempted this using two different commands: nlm and nloptr. I get different results for both of these. As such, I was wondering if it is normal for them to differ and if so, which of the commands I should use for this specific question. Another issue I have is that I have to be able to estimate the standard errors of each the parameters and have no idea how to do this.

Here is my code. The wage, unemployment_duration and employed vectors are all vectors of pre-existing data:

```
####################### Guessing initial values ###################
mu_guess<- 10
sigma_w_guess<- 3.61
lambda_guess<- 5

#Vector of inputs
initial_guess <- c(mu_guess,sigma_w_guess,lambda_guess)

#Lower and upper bounds
lower_bound <- c(0,0,0)
upper_bound <- c(Inf,Inf,Inf)

####################### Specification 1 ###################################
negative_log_likelihood <- function(x){
  #Parameters to estimate
  mu <- x[1]
  sigma_w <- x[2]
  lambda <- x[3]
  
  #Rate of leaving unemployment
  hu <- lambda*(1 - plnorm(reservation_wage, meanlog = mu,
                           sdlog = sigma_w, lower.tail = TRUE,
                           log.p = FALSE))
  #Predefining vectors
  fu<-matrix(0,1458,1)
  fu_hat <- matrix(0,1458,1)
  fa<- matrix(0,1458,1)
  L <- matrix(0,1458,1)
  
  for (i in 1:1458){
    
    #Probability of a completed spell (vector)
    fu[i,1] = hu*exp(-hu*unemployment_duration[i,1])
  
    #Probability of an ongoing spell (vector)
    fu_hat[i,1] = exp(-hu*unemployment_duration[i,1])
    
    #Distribution of wage accounting for truncation at reservation wage
    fa[i,1] = dlnorm(wage[i,1], meanlog = mu, sdlog = sigma_w,
                     log = FALSE)/(1 - plnorm(reservation_wage,
                                         meanlog = mu, sdlog = sigma_w,
                                         lower.tail = TRUE,log.p = FALSE))
    
    #log-ikelihood of an observation
    if(employed[i,1]==1){L[i,1]=log(fu[i,1]*fa[i,1])}
    else{L[i,1]=log(fu_hat[i,1])}
}
  #Log-likelihood function
  neg_log_lik <- -sum(L)
  
    return(neg_log_lik)
}
```

Comment: this is a very interesting question, but it will be hard to help without a [mcve]. You should *not* get different answers with different optimizers; which has a better (i.e. lower) negative log-likelihood?  Have you compared results with the more commonly used `optim()` as well?  The `bbmle` package can help with downstream tasks like estimating parameter std devs/confidence intervals ...

Comment: Thanks for the comment! So unconstrained nlm has the lower log-negative likelihood. The estimates under nlm are very close to those of unconstrained optim() (up to the second decimal point). However, I am a bit worried because when I use these commands, I can't add the lower and upper bounds for the parameters (an error occurs saying it needs finite values of the function). When I attempt unconstrained optimization, the parameters returned are within the interval though.